Hide first n columns in window
When I compare pieces of code in vim, often I'd like to open a vertical split, so that I can see and compare more lines. Oftentimes, the code is indented, and I use zs to position the code at a suitable indent.
However, when I scroll across blank lines, the cursor jumps to the start of the line and pushes my code away. I know that virtualedit and nostartofline can prevent the horizontal position from resetting for motions, but I have to remember to reset these values or else other splits of the buffer are affected. Moreover, virtualedit changes vim behaviour too much; e.g. allowing the cursor to be on a location without text.
Is there some way to simply make vim hide the first nth columns? I wouldn't mind that the cursor not show up if its in the hidden first nth columns. That would be a good solution to my problem.
Thanks.
